# Determining valid lengths of the fourth edge of a quadrilateral whose other edge-lengths are $3$, $7$, $15$

Tags: geometry

Andrew has 30 thin sticks and each of them has a different length from $1$cm to $30$cm. He chooses three sticks: $3$cm, $7$cm, and $15$cm. He wants to choose another stick to make a cuadrilateral. How many sticks can he choose? (He can no longer choose the ones he's already chosen).

Comment: One edge of a polygon is the shortest distance between its endpoints; traversing the polygon via all the other edges will be a longer path between those two vertices.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that the lengths are integers. Note that the fourth side can be as small as we please. Furthermore, it cannot be longer than the sum of the other three lengths, so that we have the tightest bounds $$1\le x\le3+7+15=25,$$ where $x$ is the length of the last side of the quadrilateral. Thus, he can choose from any of $30-5-3=22$ sticks in the given set.

Comment: But by your idea, the $x+7+3 \ge 25$ but what I can't understand is why the lengths have to sum more than the other if it isn't a triangle.

Comment: @Vmimi I believe you wanted to write $x\le3+7+15$. This has to be the case, otherwise (i.e., supposing the fourth side exceeded the sum of the other three) you do not have a closed figure. I assume by quadrilateral you meant a simple **closed** figure.

Comment: Yes it´s a closed figure. What I meant was $x+7+3 \ge 15$

Comment: @Vmimi I don't know where you got that from. I did not write any such thing. I wrote instead that $x\ge1$ and $x\le25$.